# How Add Update at my Haskel Yesod Project

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

guys, i need suggestions to add Update at my Haskell Project.
I'm using Yesod.

That's the part of my code that i List all the animals and for each one, a button to delete the animal.
How can i make a Update, like this way ?

Thanks.

```
getListarAnimalR :: Handler Html
getListarAnimalR = do
             listaAnm <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc AnimalsNome]
             defaultLayout $ [whamlet|
                 <h1> Animais cadastrados:
                 $forall Entity pid animals <- listaAnm
                     <a href=@{ChecarAnimalR pid}> #{animalsNome animals} 
                     <form method=post action=@{ChecarAnimalR pid}> 
                         <input type="submit" value="Deletar Animal"><br>
             |] >> toWidget [lucius|
                form  { display:inline; }
                input { background-color: #ecc; border:0;}
             |]


    postChecarAnimalR :: AnimalsId -> Handler Html
    postChecarAnimalR pid = do
         runDB $ delete pid
         redirect ListarAnimalR

formAnimal :: Form Animals
formAnimal = renderDivs $ Animals <$>
           areq textField "Nome: " Nothing <*>
           areq intField "Idade: " Nothing <*>
           areq (selectField racas) "Raca" Nothing
```

Comment: what is the problem with this code (aside from the layout)? Is it compiling? If not what are the compiler errors? Because on a first glance you should have a button and a link both deleting your animal

Comment: or is the question how you can *edit* one animal? Well in this case the easiest solution is probably to add a link/button that will navigate the user to another route/form - you probably have this somewhere for new animals (wherever you use `formAnimal`) - the only additional work you have is to first load the animal and then replace the `Nothing` parts in your `formAnimal` with the data from this animal (just change the function to `formAnmial :: Maybe Animal -> Form Animal`)

Comment: Thanks Carsten! Doing this, chance the form to Maybe Animals it could still be used to register animals? Thinking when the user acess the form tô insert a Animal, i wont need the Nothing to the fields come empty? And how can i send the Animal atributes to the Form? I understood what you said, but can you show me in code? Thanks alooot

Comment: if you have `input :: Maybe Animal` and assuming one of the field is named `nome` you should be able to replace `areq textField "Nome: " Nothing <*>` with `areq textField "Nome: " (fmap nome input) <*> ...` - then you can use the existing with `formAnmial Nothing` and can provide values with `formAnmial (Just data)`

Comment: it's explained here too: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms (look for `carAForm`) - only difference is that it' using `<$>` instead of `fmap` (it's the same - so pick what suits you)